# Find strings in L^4

Tags: formal-languages, sets

```
Let L = {ab,aa,baa}.
```

I need to find L^4. From my understanding, I union the set.

So:

```
L^1 = {ab,aa,baa}
L^2 = {abab,abaa,abbaa,aaab,aaaa,aabaa,baaab,baaaa,baabaa}
L^3 = {abababab,abababaa,abababba,....} ??
```

I concatenate L^3 with L^2 as I did above correct? And then I concatenate L^4 with L^3?

Comment: What do you mean by "union"?

Comment: I'd probably code up a program to compute all of the elements in L^4.

Comment: Cross-posted on math.se: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953497/find-strings-in-l4.

Comment: You're right, I did "cross_post" it. I did it because I was recommended to post it on either one, so I chose both. Is that OK?

Comment: I think you mean Cartesian Product of the set and not the union. Because `A x A = A^2` while `A U A = A`.

Comment: Concatenate is what I meant

Comment: It is counter to etiquette to cross-post simultaneously. Only if you get no answer on one site after a few days you should post it on another.

Comment: Actually, a correction.  This is not just etiquette; it is a site rule.  StackExchange rules prohibit cross-posting.  Also, even if you get no answer after a few days, still it is not allowed to cross-post  (though it is OK to ask the moderators to migrate the question).  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917.

Comment: Note the original question was on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133627/finding-strings-in-l4). I recommend removing the question from SO and Math exchange sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $L^4$ consists of all words $xyzw$ where $x,y,z,w \in L$. In our case, there are (at most) $3^4 = 81$ such words, but I don't see why you'd want to write all of them. If you want, you can also compute $L^4$ by squaring $L$ twice: $L^4 = (L^2)^2$. Then there is no need to compute $L^3$.

Comment: I understand. However, is my explanation of how to do it still correct? Lets say at least to my L^3? How'd you do the bold L with the 4 at the top? I forget the correct term for the 4?

Comment: I can't understand your explanation, but your computation of $L^2$ is correct. The question is stupid in any case.

Comment: Excuse me? Stupid? Who are you to judge? This site is for questions correct?

Comment: I meant the question you are trying to solve, not your question on the site. My criticism is directed at your professor.

Comment: The question is stupid since the answer is very long. A better question would have been $L^3$ or $L^4$ for $|L| = 2$.